# Schema.org tags for dynamically created search results?

Tags: javascript, schema.org

When adding Schema.org tags to a page, should I include items which are dynamically created - e.g. a component which only exists on a page after a user has entered a search term?

Or should these tags be reserved solely for static objects that will always be on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema.org is used for search engines. So you have to think about which content a search engine has access to.

Search engines don't necessarily wait for dynamic content (for example content loaded via Ajax, or after user interaction). So all Schema.org markup added to the page after the initial page load may not have the impact you would like.

In your example content is shown after a user enters a search term. A search engine would not get to that content, so adding Schema.org there would be of little use.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I wasn't too sure to what extent crawlers might simulate data entry based on their query but it does make sense they wouldn't necessarily have the time

Comment: This thread might be interesting for you: [markup is dynamically built](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29064209/does-schema-org-markup-work-if-markup-is-dynamically-built-with-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1) . It provides some more insight.

Answer (score 1):

Some consumers support JavaScript (so they could make use of the structured data on content that is created on the client-side), some consumers don’t support JavaScript (so they can’t access that structured data).

Consumers could be web services (like search engines), but also user agents and tools (like browser extensions). As an example, [Google supports it only for JSON-LD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29066759/1591669), but not for Microdata or RDFa.

If it’s not much work for you, go with it. It can’t hurt, but could help. If it’s work, you might want to consider which consumers you want to support, and then check their documentation.