# Adding JSON-LD with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json-ld

I am trying to implement structure data using JSON-LD. What I am doing is dynamically get content using jQuery and making JSON format and appending inside the `head` element.

```html
<script id="dynamicJSONLD"></script>
```

```javascript
$(document).ready(function(){
var product_name = $(.product-pg .product-name).text();
data = {
               "@context": "https://schema.org",
               "@type": "Product",
               "url": "https://www.example.com/productone",
               "name": product_name  
            };

//creating the script element and storing the JSON-LD

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = "application/ld+json";
script.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

//OR

//storing the JSON-LD using ID
$("#dynamicJSONLD").html(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

Do both ways (creating the `script` element and storing the JSON-LD / storing the JSON-LD using ID) work? Which is the best implementation way? Also, does Google crawl dynamically added JSON-LD like above, using JavaScript?

Comment: About your last question: [Does Schema.org markup work if markup is dynamically built with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29064209/1591669)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, Google can crawl dynamically added JSON-LD, as explained in [this Google article](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data) on the topic:

> Google can read JSON-LD data when it is dynamically injected
> into the page's contents, such as by JavaScript code or embedded
> widgets in your content management system.

Both methods will definitely work, but if you're going to store the JSON-LD using ID you'll need to add the required *type* attribute to the script:

```
<script id="dynamicJSONLD" type="application/ld+json"></script>
```

Once you finish adding your markup, make sure to test it with [Google's Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool)!

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
var Client = require("node-rest-client").Client;
var client = new Client();
var args = {
    headers: { "Accept": "application/ld+json, */*;q=0.5" }
 };

client.get(url+query,args, function (data, response) {
    ......
}
```